# venir de faire qqc, to have just done something

Tags: traduction, verbes, adverbes

While "venir de faire qqc" means to have just done something, I always wondered if you could actually use the direct translation as well. I am assuming this would be the same for Spanish (acabar de).

> J'ai juste mangé mon repas.

or maybe:

> J'ai juste fini de manger mon repas.

Just wondering if the "juste" here would convey the same meaning.

Thanks in advance.

J

Comment: While they both talk about just in the past, this is not a duplicate question by any means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in this first sentence, the English "just" does not have "juste" for rendering in that context. In that context "juste" means "only" ("seulement" in French).

- J'ai juste mangé mon repas.
- I ate only my meal. *That is to say I didn't pilfer from my neighbour's plate, didn't cheat on the rations allowed so as to have twice my share, etc.*

Here is the precise meaning (TLFi) and examples so as to get a more complete picture of that usage;

> 4. [Avec une valeur restrictive] Exactement, mais pas plus; seulement, à peine.
>
>    - Avoir juste le temps de; arriver, commencer, se mettre, réussir juste à; venir juste de; avoir juste ce qu'il faut; avoir tout juste de quoi vivre; être tout juste bon à, capable de.
>    - Qu'est-ce que je demande? (...) Juste le nécessaire et un peu de superflu, pas davantage.
>    - Elle tombait si épaisse, la neige, qu'on y voyait tout juste à dix pas.
>    - Sa robe Est longue juste assez pour qu'elle ne dérobe Qu'à moitié sous ses plis jaloux le bout charmant D'un pied malicieux imperceptiblement.
>    - Tu ne pourrais pas t'arrêter, juste pour respirer un peu.

For a translation of "I just finished my meal" you couldn't use "J'ai juste fini de manger mon repas."; "juste" would be "seulement" again; you'd have to say this ;

- Je viens juste de finir mon repas.

In that case "juste" is "just" (à peine).

Comment: Je commence sérieusement a en avoir assez des réponses prescriptives qui recopient des définitions de dictionnaire en faisant fi de l'usage de tous les jours. Ça n'aide pas les gens à comprendre la langue.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Nous, nous en avons sérieusement assez des choix fantaisistes qui font fi de l'usage établi lorsqu'ils n'y apportent rien par des changement inutiles et seulement une pagaille indicible alors qu'en préservant ce qui est bon et utile on s'épargne de sans cesse recréer les mêmes choses et faire travailler les gens pour rien alors qu'il n'y a pas assez de temps pour seulement apprendre ce qu'il faudrait savoir.